# SVG to PNG using imagick changing colour

Tags: php, svg, image-processing, png, imagick

I'm using imagick to convert SVG to PNG, but after the conversion the colour is slightly different, I've done the following snippet to change the SVG.

```
$src = 'File Path';
$im = new Imagick();
$svg = file_get_contents($src);
$im->readImageBlob($svg);
$im->setImageFormat("png32");
$im->resizeImage(3000, 3000, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode( $im ) . '" />';
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

Kindly help me with a way how can I convert SVG to PNG using php and maintaining exact colour codes.

Comment: We can't see your SVG file nor the PNG it produces.